# SQL Query where a specific column should have two specific values but have just one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the cryptic title, but i didn't find a better question

I have a Table with lets say these Data:

```
Table Article

ID    ArticleNumber    Type
1     10               1
2     10               3
3     20               1
4     30               1
5     30               3
```

I'm looking for the 3. Row where no type 3 article exists but a type 1 article exists.

I think it have to be a very easy SQL query but i can't find a solution...

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all ArticleNumbers for which exists a row with type = 1 but there is no row with type = 3, use this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Article a
WHERE
  a.`Type` = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM
      Article a2
    WHERE
      a2.`Type` = 3
      AND a2.ArticleNumber = a.ArticleNumber
  )
```

Comment: easy to maintain and faster than Frank Schmitt's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first ID by aggregating the original data (see subquery), then you can filter those records where could be any anomalies.

If you want, you can change the aggregation to `COUNT`, then you can compare the count for each types.

```
SELECT
  ArticleNumber
FROM (
  -- Conditional aggregation to find the first ID for each type per ArticleNumber
  SELECT
      ArticleNumber
    , MIN(CASE WHEN Type = 1 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS Type_1
    , MIN(CASE WHEN Type = 3 THEN ID ELSE NULL END) AS Type_3
  GROUP BY
    ArticleNumber
) AS X
WHERE
  Type_1 IS NULL
  OR Type_2 IS NULL
```

**Note** You can change the above query to use the `HAVING` keyword instead of subquery if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, using `MINUS` to remove the articles with Type 3:

```
select ID, ArticleNumber from Article where type = 1
MINUS
select ID, ArticleNumber from Article where type = 3
```

UPDATE

After re-reading your question, I guess you want to also have those with Type = 3, but where no row with Type = 1 exists. For this, you can use `COUNT DISTINCT`:

```
select * from (
  select ID, ArticleNumber, count(distinct type) as type_cnt
  from Article
  group by ID, ArticleNumber
) 
where type_cnt < 2
```

Answer (score -1):

You mean you want all rows where type is not 3?

That would be this statement:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
    `Article` 
WHERE 
    `type` != 3;
```

After re-reading your question I understand your problem. I would go with Eriks solution.